# Can't get value checkbox checked form php

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

My checkbox does not get value after sending form ...

**My form**

```
<input name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="username" />
<input type="checkbox" id="atur_peg" name="atur_peg" value="Ya" checked />
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php

echo $username=$_POST['username']; // this can get value
echo $atur_peg=$_POST['atur_peg']; // and this can't get value

?>
```

**this full form**

```
<form class="cmxform" id="tambahuser"  name="kepuasan_user" method="post" action="user/tambahuserproses.php">

<label>Username</label>
:
<input name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="username"  size="40" maxlength="50" />
<span id="pesan"></span>
  <br />
  <label>Password</label>
: <input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" id="password" class="showpassword" size="40" maxlength="50" />
       <p>
<label><strong>Atur untuk Pegawai ?</strong></label><input type="checkbox" id="atur_peg" name="atur_peg" value="Ya" checked />Ya
  </p>
    </form>
```

How to correct ?

Comment: print_r your $_POST and see what's in there

Comment: is there a post submission at all

Comment: I don't find a problem in your syntax, however, make sure you use `isset` for `$_POST`, so that there will not be any WARNING.

Comment: no error in this part of the code, if checkbox is checked then it work.

Comment: @Qile : i have do that , and not printed

Comment: Your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox is checked you will get a value for it in your $_POST.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="username" />
<input type="checkbox" id="atur_peg" name="atur_peg" value="Ya" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['atur_peg'])) {
  $checkBoxValue = "yes";
} else {
  $checkBoxValue = "no";
}

echo $checkBoxValue;
?>
```

Comment: What will echo $_POST['atur_peg'] print?

Comment: it will return value="Ya" this means Ya..

Comment: hello @Priya ... always get 'no'

Comment: Then OPs code is will work. What your answer is adding to solution?

Comment: Dear please just copy and run that code from your localhost it is working fine..without post data it will always return no..

Comment: if you will submit/post the form it will return yes and the value of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If the box is not checked, the value does not exist.
So

```
if ( empty($_POST['atur_peg']) )
{
    // not checked
}
else
{
    // checked
}
```

Comment: It is written in input tag that is CHECKED

Comment: It does not mean that it is at the time the code is run.
Maybe the OP wants the value even if the box is not checked.

Comment: i write this if ( empty($_POST['atur_peg']) )
{
    echo "no";
}
else
{
    echo "yes";
} 

and always 'no' if checked or not cheked

Comment: Can you post the full <form></form> code please.
Also, what do you see when you add print_r( $_POST )?

Comment: i have changed it, pleas look again

Comment: Where is your submit button?
What happens if you add 
    <input type="submit">
to your form?
How do you submit the form?